# Does a mac support UAS (USB Attached SCSI)?

Tags: mac, bootcamp, usb

Does a mac with USB 3.0 support UAS (USB Attached SCSI)? If it does, how can we enable it in OS X and bootcamp? I need better speeds for my external RAID.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what you need is already in Lion see this blog [OSX Mountain Lion 10.8 UAS UASP USB Attach SCSI drivers](http://fortysomethinggeek.blogspot.com/2013/04/osx-mountain-lion-108-uas-uasp-usb.html)

Note I have nothing to do with the blog.  It was at the top of the list when I **googled USB Attached SCSI OSX**

Comment: How about bootcamp? I use bootcamp quite a lot.

Comment: @jw382 It depends on the version of Windows you are using.

Comment: Windows 8 Professional

Comment: @jw382 That is supported in W8 .. so it comes down to what hardware you are running it all on.

Comment: Do I need a specific driver to enable the feature? It seems that I don't have the USB attached SCSI driver under storage controllers in device management.